# OS X (Cocoa etc.) idiomatic way of creating cancelable periodic operation

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, pthreads

Is there an OSX / Cocoa idiomatic way of creating a cancelable thread performing a periodic operation, i.e.

```
while not cancelled:
  cancelable sleep for N seconds
  if sleep was cancelled:
     return
  else:
     do periodic task
```

In POSIX, it can be created with a thread, a conditional variable and a flag; I've written a [simple implementation](https://gist.github.com/ikonst/e7fdaddcc7973f44e7a3) (link to gist; omitted from the question for brevity), but it's truly a textbook example. As you can see, it is many lines of code, and I'm sure such a typical thing has a simple solution.

Options I've considered:

- `NSTimer` provides the same semantics, but executes on the UI thread.
- Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) lacks cancelation, and I do want to be able to cancel the operation as soon as possible.

Comment: `NSTimer`s created with `scheduledTimer...` run on the _current_ thread, not necessarily the main thread. You can also create the timer and later add it to any thread's run loop.

Comment: I didn't realize there can be multiple run loops. In fact, "Each NSThread object, including the application’s main thread, has an NSRunLoop object automatically created for it as needed". Didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `NSOperationQueue` and an `NSOperation`. These classes use gcd. An `NSOperation` can be cancelled with the `cancel` operation.

Comment: The delayed NSOperations will only be processed when their time comes, so it's not very different than - say, `dispatch_after` with a weak reference to your class (assuming your class' `dealloc` is when you want to stop the periodic operation).